# React state having select not updating once the form gets submitted

Tags: reactjs

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("");
const [totalValue, setTotalValue] = useState("");

const handleChange = (e) => {
     setValue(e.target.value)
}

const addDataHandler = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     setTotalValue(+totalValue+value);
};

return (
<form onSubmit = {addDataHandler}>
<select value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
);
```

I need to add the selected value to a new state only if form gets submitted. My code doesn't fetch the current value of the state.

Comment: `onSubmitt` should be `onSubmit`. `setVTotalValue` should be `setTotalValue`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 setVTotalValue(+totalValue+setValue);
```

You have a typo above

set--V--TotalValue

Answer (score 0):

You need to like this

```
const [totalValue, setTotalValue] = useState("");

const addDataHandler = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     setTotalValue(+totalValue+value);
};
```

This is wrong `setTotalValue(+totalValue+setValue);`

In case value and totalvalue are number you should do this

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
const [totalValue, setTotalValue] = useState(0);
```

Comment: mistakenly commented as setTotalValue(+totalValue+setValue)  even though i use  this setTotalValue(+totalValue+value); i am getting the same problem.  
I think we need to pass the current updated state value to addDataHandler...

Comment: Did you do this? const [totalValue, setTotalValue] = useState(0);

Comment: We don't need to pass it.

Comment: try to give name on <select name={"whatever"} />

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is property types. The program is trying to add strings instead of numbers. You could simply change your initial use states to numbers and parseInt the event.target.value like so:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(2);
const [totalValue, setTotalValue] = useState(0);

const handleChange = (e) => {
  setValue(parseInt(e.target.value));
};

const addDataHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const sum = totalValue + value;
  setTotalValue(sum);
};

return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={addDataHandler}>
        <select value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
      {totalValue}
      <br />
      {value}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Doesn't seems to work...i dont want to return the value, if u console.log(totalValue) in addDataHandler it doesnt gets updated...i want to get updated there itself

Comment: Hi, so I think that the state is currently updating properly, but the placement of the console.log into the handler is updating at the same time, meaning that you will get your log one life cycle late. If you click the button a few times, it will appear as if it is one behind you in the console.log. If you insert some js at the bottom of your return (like I just added above) that calls on the {value} variable, it should show you what you want. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to see the value my case is i have another select that stores some value in another state so on form submit i should divide this total value and that another select value